# How to start external program and pass in CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, startup, os.system

I am trying to start a program and write a saved CSV file to it.

I have the following code to start the program, that works fine:

```
os.startfile('C:\Program Files\Files\CSV_Reader')
```

But I'm not sure how to open the CSV File. I tried a few other options like:

```
os.system('start CSV_Reader.exe "{0}C:\Program Files\Files\card_kingdom.csv"'.format(sys.path[0], ))
```

But I get the following error message:

> C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/JJ/PycharmProjects/Buylist/CK_file_test
>   The system cannot find the file CSV_Reader.exe.

I know that the directory is right, because when I call the `os.startfile` function it opens the program.
Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use popen like it:

```
    import subprocess
    subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files\Files\CSV_Reader.exe" , "C:\Program Files\Files\card_kingdom.csv"])
```

Comment: It opened the program just fine, but the csv file doesn't open inside the program. Any idea how I can troubleshoot that? Thanks!

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Turned out the program I was using had some issues